# 'From' field disabled when retrieving Facebook comment information using Graph API V3.1

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, httprequest

I'm trying to extract informations about comments from Facebook page post (I'm Admin) via Http request using Facebook Graph API

**graph.facebook.com/2288441345503360_2289495187064649?fields=created_time,admin_creator,message,from&access_token=xxx**

I can't extract all the fileds, I got from the URL above just ***created_time*** and ***message***

However ***from*** and ***admin_creator*** fields are disabled.

[image]

Comment: When you hover over those fields, you should get a tooltip, no?

Comment: Yes: 'Field is empty or disalowed by the access token'

Comment: Ok @CBroe, I didn't see the tooltip untill you noticed, I'll try to generate another access_token.